# React Native, Android: "No virtual method setDefaultColorSchemeParams"

Tags: android, react-native, adyen

I am desperately trying to build my app with React Native in Android. But my app everytime crashes at a certain point, outputting this report via logCat.

```
2023-04-27 01:50:30.277 11317-11317/.**.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: *..**app, PID: 11317
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDefaultColorSchemeParams(Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabColorSchemeParams;)Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder; in class Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder' appears in /data/app/~~9UvaD_8JVVP_mGLBatSGCA==/.**.**ap-qkU8xjKJ6YR0nXmHu5c05w==/base.apk)
at com.adyen.checkout.redirect.RedirectUtil.createCustomTabIntent(RedirectUtil.kt:129)
at com.adyen.checkout.redirect.RedirectUtil.createRedirectIntent(RedirectUtil.kt:112)
at com.adyen.checkout.redirect.RedirectDelegate.makeRedirect(RedirectDelegate.kt:36)
at com.adyen.checkout.redirect.RedirectDelegate.makeRedirect(RedirectDelegate.kt:23)
```

Device: Pixel XL API 33, Android Emulator, Version Tiramisu
OS: MacBook Pro M1

Any ideas?

Comment: Never seen this before, could it be a dependency conflict? Using a different version of androidx.browser or Adyen SDK (it should be v1.3.0)?

Answer (score 2):

Just resolved the problem: you need to update build.gradle to the newest androidX browser version, if you explicitly set it to an older version, like we did:

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
        }
    }
```

Set it to `1.4.0` did the trick!